# How to add a bookmark for a Tkinter Text widget?

Tags: python, tkinter

I've got a text widget, that is filled with some text. I'd like to add a simple bookmark (by Y) **without** using the text indices (e.g. "50.2"). How can I do it?

I've tried:

```
from tkinter import *


bookmarks = []  # create a list for bookmarks

def add_bookmark():
    bookmark = textbox.yview()  # get the vertical position of the view
    bookmarks.append(bookmark)  # and add it to the bookmarks' list

def goto_bookmark(bookmark):
    textbox.yview_moveto(bookmark)  # set the vertical positionn of the view

root = Tk()  # create a root window

# set the column's and row's weight
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

textbox = Text(root)  # create the Text widget
scrollbar = Scrollbar(root, command=textbox.yview)  # create the Scrollbar widget, and attach it to the Text widget
textbox["yscrollcommand"] = scrollbar.set  # attach the Text widget to the Scrollbar
# show the widgets using grid geometry manager
textbox.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nswe")
scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nswe")
Button(root, text="Add bookmark", command=add_bookmark).grid()  # create and show the "Add bookmark" button
Button(root, text="Goto lastbookmark", command=lambda: goto_bookmark(bookmarks[-1])).grid()  # create and show the "Goto last bookmark" button

textbox.insert(END, "TEXT\n" *1000)  # fill the textbox with something

root.mainloop()  # start the mainloop
```

But I've got this exception when I am trying to go to a bookmark:

> _tkinter.TclError: expected floating-point number but got "0.7501873126873126 0.7741633366633367"

Answer (score 1):

Change the button command as following:

```
Button(root, text="Goto lastbookmark", command=lambda: goto_bookmark(bookmarks[-1][-1])).grid()  # create and show the "Goto last bookmark" button
```

Answer (score 1):

Tkinter's `text.yview()` method returns a tuple containing the normalized start and end points of the text box. In this instance, you only care about the first element, the top position of the window, so you can pull that element out of the tuple and save that as your bookmark. This fix is as simple as adding `[0]` to the end of line 8. Here is a working version:

```
from tkinter import *

bookmarks = []  # create a list for bookmarks

def add_bookmark():

    bookmark = textbox.yview()[0]   # yview returns the start and end point of the view. We only care about the start
                                    # point so we can pull out the first element in the tuple.
    bookmarks.append(bookmark)  # and add it to the bookmarks' list

def goto_bookmark(bookmark):
    textbox.yview_moveto(bookmark)  # set the vertical positionn of the view

root = Tk()  # create a root window

# set the column's and row's weight
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

textbox = Text(root)  # create the Text widget
scrollbar = Scrollbar(root, command=textbox.yview)  # create the Scrollbar widget, and attach it to the Text widget
textbox["yscrollcommand"] = scrollbar.set  # attach the Text widget to the Scrollbar
# show the widgets using grid geometry manager
textbox.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nswe")
scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nswe")
Button(root, text="Add bookmark", command=add_bookmark).grid()  # create and show the "Add bookmark" button
Button(root, text="Goto lastbookmark", command=lambda: goto_bookmark(bookmarks[-1])).grid()  # create and show the "Goto last bookmark" button

textbox.insert(END, "TEXT\n" *1000)  # fill the textbox with something

root.mainloop()  # start the mainloop
```

Answer (score 1):

The text widget supports a feature called "marks". Think of them like named indexes.

You can set a mark with the `mark_set` method. For example, to set a mark at the start of line 5 you would do it like this:

```
textbox.mark_set("bookmark1", "5.0")
```

Later you can jump to that bookmark with the `see` method, which scrolls an index into view.

```
textbox.see("bookmark1")
```